# Reset search history to search from the start with CTRL + r

Tags: command-line

When I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in Linux, the command history is searched from the last finding.

How do I reset the search, so that I am able to search from the start?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please? Do you mean you want to find the _oldest_ match first?

Comment: I don't really think this is possible, if you want more advanced history funciton, you should check out [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, nor what terminal/shell you're asking about. I do what you're asking about regularly, but how done can vary on details you didn't provide.  Note: on some I exit the search & hit ^R again.. but it varies on shell at a minimum.

Comment: @pLumo Actually, bash does have a `forward-search-history` function (see `Commands for Manipulating the History` in `man bash`) but it's mapped to `Ctrl+S` by default which blocks input on most terminals.

Comment: I usually address the problem by using a different letter I know existed in an earlier command with `Ctrl+r`.

Answer (score 0):

To do more advanced searching than provided by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:

`$ man history`  tells about a good deal of options.
but then,
`$ history | grep search-terms` might be easier to understand, as it is more "standard"